# is there any way for bulk ignore in svn like git ignore file?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I am using SVN for source version system. I use AnkhSVN plugin for Visual Studio 2015 for integrating SVN with the IDE. Now I need a file like git ignore file in svn to bulk ignore. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way but not in form of a file. `svn:ignore` or `svn:global-ignores` versioned properties are used for this. You can also configure ignore pattern in client runtime configuration area (`%APPDATA%\Subversion\config` file). Read the documentation:

- [TortoiseSVN | Ignoring Files And Directories](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html)
- [SVNBook | Ignoring Unversioned Items](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html)

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend you to use Visual SVN ans Tortoise SVN, once you have installed this tools Visual SVN call Tortoise SVN when you need to do a commit.

Also you can ignore path and file, but you have to do a commit of this ignore and after you have to do an update to ignore this files.

This is once you have installed Visual SVN:

[image]

And this is you can ignore files:
[image]

And this is Tortoise when you try to do a Commit:

[image]

[image]

I spec this help you.